# EF Update current migration file instead of create a new one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I know it's against the purpose of migration, but it doesn't make sense to me to make a new migration file for every single changes that I do to the model.

I start with enabling migration, then initial the migration and visual studio make a `201502151515_initial.cs`

i do some changes in the 201502151515_initial.cs file and go for update-database.

then I understand I have some bug in the  model. 
then if i try to `update-database` it will fail and show me this error:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration. You can use the Add-Migration
>   command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.

if I try to add-migration, then it will create another file for me

is it anyway to update the current `201502151515_initial.cs` file?

I can do it manually that is a hell of task to make sure everything is fine. 
I can delete the current file and create it again, in this case i have inconsistency with database(because I already update-database).
or find a better way to update the current file.

is it any better way to do it?

Comment: The only thing you should change in the generated migration file is data manipulation (`Sql` function and such). If you don't like how EF generated the model difference, you need to change your model - entities, configurations, etc. Then when you're happy with those changes, either delete the unapplied migration or run `Add-Migration <same name, no dates> -Force` to re-scaffold the migration. Note, that this will completely overwrite the file. It essentially just skips the delete and keeps the date part of the file the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would prefer automatic migrations?.  This is similar to the solution you are looking for.

You don't need to add migrations, just push to the database

```
Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations
Update-Database
```

Comment: unfortunately in ASP .NET Core 1.1 `Enable-Migration` is not supported: `Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations.`

Answer (score -1):

in dotnet core it becomes easy.

just `dotnet ef migrations remove` then `dotnet ef migrations add init`